# ScreenUpdating doesn't update screen in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I've code that takes 30+ mins to run. I have set screen updating to false while most of the code runs but every now and again I turn it to true and straight back to false.

In 2003, 2007 and 2010 this allows the screen to temporarily update. In 2013 it doesn't work.

How can I make Excel 2013 temporarily update the screen mid-macro?

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Do loads of stuff here
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Enable to refresh screen
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Disable again
    ' Do more stuff here
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using `DoEvents` before updating the screen?

Comment: Here is a question which might help with your query by the way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863641/doevents-doesnt-do-the-events-why

Answer (score 2):

DoEvents worked for me. I don't know what causes this but inserting DoEvents in the Loop Method seems to correct the issue for me when I use it.

```
Sub LoopMethod
    Foreach i in Identity
        Call Loopthis 
    Next For
EndSub

Sub Loopthis 
    DoEvents
    select.Cells(i, 6)
EndSub
```

Answer (score 1):

I do place this code right before every event/screen I want to update and works fine for me:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
DoEvents

Sheets("Main").Select   'Screen to update
```

Also I put the code inside every loop I use to write someting in the Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Activating another worksheet and then again activating the required worksheet worked for me - I had a code where the screen updating failed, I activated another worksheet and then again the one I was working on, it updated the current screen.

```
application.ScreenUpdating = False

''''''code'''''''

Thisworkbook.worksheets(any otherworksheet in workbook).activate
Thisworkbook.worksheets(current worksheet).activate

application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have found the issue can be solved by jumping to another cell. You could do something like this:

```
Dim Ac as object
Set Ac = ActiveCell
Ac.Offset(0,IIf(Ac.Column = Application.Columns.Count, -1, 1)).Activate
Ac.Activate
```

As to the how or why of this behaviour I don't know (yet). As far as I have found now, it has something to do with the active cell before deactivating screen update, being the same as after reactivating screen update. But I haven