# Code to insert n blank cells after every row is very slow

Tags: vba, optimization, excel

This would be my code, but it takes a lifetime if I have over 5000 rows, and 1 column. Is there a way to reduce the query time?

```
Sub InsertRows() 
    Dim numRows As Integer 
    Dim r As Long 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
    numRows = 11 

    For r = r To 1 Step -1 
        ActiveSheet.Rows(r + 1).Resize(numRows).Insert 
    Next r 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Takes about 25 sec for me. Quite normal for the operation. Try using `.Insert xlShiftDown`, but that won't matter much anyway.

Comment: Yea, it's pretty much the same. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you can't *effectively* reduce the time, you can make it *appear* shorter with a progressbar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181164/progress-bar-in-vba-excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This took < 1 second.

```
Sub InsertRows()

Dim numberOfValues As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim values As Variant

Const numberOfEmptyRows As Long = 11

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' count values in column A
numberOfValues = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' populate array with numbers
ReDim values(1 To numberOfValues, 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To numberOfValues
  values(i, 1) = i
Next i

' I know there is a better way to do this part...
Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(numberOfValues, 2)).Value = values
For i = 1 To numberOfEmptyRows - 1
  Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(numberOfValues, 0)).Value = values
Next i

' sort by values inserted in column B
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code uses a helper column (in this case, B) to insert a number sequence next to the target range. Then it adds the same numbers N times below itself, and sorts on that column. Finally, it deletes the column. This is how you can quickly insert blank rows into any data set.

Change `Const numberOfEmptyRows As Long = 11` if you want to insert more/less blank rows. There is a limit to how many records this technique can handle (and how many blank rows can be inserted) before you hit Excel's row limit.

Comment: Awesome. I have had similar issues with the slowness of excel updating the display. Good to know I can simply set the updating to false.

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy, your code is very nice. But if there isn't any content in 'A' column while the other columns have some the result of sorting will go wrong.

So, I will use UsedRange to get numberOfValues as below.

```
 Set r2Arrange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

count values in column A:

```
numberOfValues = r2Arrange.Rows.Count
```