# Can I use Excel's save progress bar?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking around and I can't really find an answer for this. Is there are way to use the progress bar that comes out when you save in Excel? I know you can use the StatusBar using Application.StatusBar = "Whatever", but anyone know how I can use the Progress Bar itself to show progress on an Excel VBA App of my own?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar/10787496#10787496

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181164/progress-bar-in-vba-excel