# How to use statusbar in excel vba on mac

Tags: excel, vba, statusbar

I'm trying to set up a progress bar so I can see if my sub is running of if i've managed to freeze excel.  I'm looking at one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181164/progress-bar-in-vba-excel), but it's not working.

Here's what I have:

```
Dim n As Integer
With Worksheets("Data_History")
    Set starting_cell_range = .Range(find_last_column("Data_History"))
    For n = 0 To 18
        starting_cell_range.Offset(n, 1) = final_array(n)
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & n & " of 18" & Format(n / 18, "0%")

    Next n
    Application.StatusBar = False

End With
```

Is it not working because I'm on a mac?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have an Application.DisplayStatusBar and it is visible? Try adding DoEvents here:

```
....
DoEvents
Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & n & " of 18" & Format(n / 18, "0%")
....
```