# Creating a Status bar or Progress bar in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, progress-bar, statusbar

I have a macro I would like to add a status bar or progress bar for. I am a Mac user and it seems like I cant create a progress bar due to the fact I dont have a user form but is there any other way? The only other feasible solution was a status bar and that too I have no clue how to start.

Im only asking for a start not the solution because I know this community doesn't do code for free. Even written help rather than code to lead me would be great!

I need a status bar or progress bar for a matrix I have coded for. Here is a sample picture. Basically as each full week finishes its 1/52 the way there (52 weeks).

[image]

Comment: See this, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080132/how-to-use-statusbar-in-excel-vba-on-mac

Comment: I need to tinker with the code to get it to work. Issue is, I don't know this original persons data and how they are doing it. Any idea for my specific issue?