# Change an image visible from False to True and back in a process in a Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Sub that takes some time to process. I want an image that says "Please Wait" to appear on top of the form while processing and then disappear. I have tried this code but it is not working:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize ()
Image1.visible=False
End Sub

Sub CommandButton1_Click ()
Image1.visible=True
'Here goes the process
Image1.visible=False
End Sub
```

Is that possible?

Comment: This kind of thing in VBA is messy at best and depends on what's going on in the process between those statements. I'd stick with `Application.StatusBar`

Comment: It appears to work for me - I created a form with an image and button.  I copied your code in to the form - replacing `'Here goes the process` with `Application.Wait Now + CDate("0:00:05")`.  The image disappeared on the click event and reappeared five seconds later.  Maybe edit your post with a `Wait` command to let people know there's meant to be code between the visible commands?

Comment: you may find this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181164/progress-bar-in-vba-excel) very helpful...

Comment: I've been looking around, and a Progress Bar is the go, but is still quite a development. I'm looking for something that can make a Visual Impact for the user without much coding.

Comment: Why would it not work? As to the best solution, this really depends on what you and your users expect as visualy suitable. What dont you like about your method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add DoEvents to enable VBA to process the re-paint event

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click ()
  Image1.visible=True
  DoEvents
  'Here goes the process
  Image1.visible=False
End Sub
```