# Copy column in one workbook and paste into another. Creating new column

Tags: vba, excel

I need to collect data every month from different workbooks and then transfer it into one master data workbook.

```
MyFile = Dir
Range("C2:D18").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

erow = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, erow), Cells(erow, erow))
```

The code above transfer my data and put them correctly for that month, column C and D. When I'm trying to transfer data the next month, it replace the ones in c and D. Instead I want the new data to get into column E and F, and the month after that G and H.

How could this be done?

Comment: Look at using a `for` loop and the `offset` function

Comment: Use indexes and loops so that your index is increased by 2 (2 columns) and the loop also read your data from multiple workbooks

Comment: You could be `erow`...just for one day

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806411/excel-vba-reading-large-amount-of-files-faster/33806725#33806725) to see how to use `Dir()` properly for reading multiples files. I'm not sure that you need to read more than one file at a time regarding your explanation but it is always good to see a *clean* example! ;)

Btw, note that `.Offset(0, 1)` is useless in the `erow = ...` as you use `.Row` at the end, and your `Offset` only affect the column of the cell.

This should work fine if you initial code do what you want :

```
MyFile = Dir
Range("C2:D18").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

eCol = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).End(xlUp).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Column
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, eCol)
```