# How to combine my vba working with a progress bar?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to reference to this progress bar sample .
http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/displaying_a_progress_indicator/

About my vb working ,I m going to generate a report that using ADO in entire worksheet . As the report generation time is too long (1 min) , I want to implement a progress bar during the report generation .Btw  , the report will be produced in a new excel file .

```
 Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()



    Dim sSQLQry As String
    Dim ReturnArray

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String



    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName


    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
    Conn.Open sconnect

   sSQLSting = "..."

   Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQLSting)

   j = 6

    Do While Not rs.EOF
with thisworkbook.worksheets("report")
.Cells(j, 1) = rs.Fields(0).Value
.Cells(j, 3) = rs.Fields(2).Value
.Cells(j, 4) = rs.Fields(3).Value
.Cells(j, 7) = rs.Fields(6).Value
End with 


 j = j + 1

  rs.MoveNext

Loop


rs.Close

Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

...copy Sheets("report") to wb ...

strFileName = "c:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report").Cells(1, 1) & ".xlsx"
'End With
wb.SaveAs strFileName
```

I read the progress bar codes . It needs to use the loop variable  `PctDone = Counter / (RowMax * ColMax)`. For my codes , it includes different works- SQL calculation , pasting on worksheets("report") , coping worksheets("report") to new workbook .Hence , I don't know how to fit my code with this progress bar application .

Reference to 
[Progress bar in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181164/progress-bar-in-vba-excel/12918056#12918056)

---

If it is impossible to implement progress bar in my case , what can i do tho let the user know "Be patient to wait about 1 min "?

Comment: You can't calculate percent done without knowing a) the total number of items you're going to process (row count in the database) and b) a counter of the number of rows you've finished processing. The second is easy - add a variable that you increment on each pass through the loop. The first is possible only if you can determine how many rows there are before you start the loop - can you do that?

Comment: @Ken White I don't know the exact row for each report ,as i use `End(xlUp).row` to finish the final report in new workbook .Also , i don't know the row that SQL is going to generate , as well as the time spending on producing and writing a new work bar .

Comment: You do not need to use a progressbar per se as @KenWhite mentioned you can't calculate the percentage. Having said that. There is an alternative. Let me search my project database. I have a sample and If I find it, I will post it. It involves listbox and a userform

Comment: @Siddharth Rout I tried to use a userform that showing "Please wait one minute` But i find that it need to spend some times on loading the new userform . That makes the whole application much loading time .

Comment: If you don't know those two things, you can't display a progress bar that shows percent complete. You could display a marquee style progress bar (the one that just goes back and forth with the little green section but doesn't show how far along you are); you can probably find an example of doing so in VBA via Google.

Comment: I am almost done...

Comment: Have you tried using CopyFromRecordset to get the data into Excel rather than looping through each record?  (e.g. `thisworkbook.worksheets("report").Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset rs` (Or is it `mrs`? You seem to have a typo in your code.)  Then it may only take a second or so, and then you won't need the progress bar.

Comment: @YowE3K i don't use `CopyFromRecords‌​et rs` because of some reason that i forgot .Then i choose to use `.Cells(j, 1) = rs.Fields(0).Value`

Comment: I even like the "marquee style progress bar" suggested by @KenWhite. I have edited my post in include a link to show animated images on the form. There are many possibliities if you want ;)

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous then more samples of progress bar can be found at [Pop up the Excel Statusbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar)

Comment: `CopyFromRecords‌​et` does flake out sometimes.  Have you tried using`GetRows`?

Comment: Can you share what is in `sSQLSting` ? You can probably aggregate the data with PivotTable or Excel formulas to make it much faster.

Comment: willing to put some effort? You can either display a gif during your operation or just change your mouse pointer (cursor) to a animated gif (ani) during the operation, Read this : http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2014/10/ajax-style-progress-display-in-vba.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use a progress bar per se as you can't calculate the percentage of work done. In such a case, it is better to let the user know of what you(or the code is doing). You could use `Application.StatusBar` to update but how many of us actually look down there? Also there's nothing more fancy than a form popping up and updating you about the status... You can also use [Animated GIFS](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?555880-Creating-Splash-Screen-in-MS-Office-2003) on the userform if you want.

> I tried to use a userform that showing "Please wait one minute` But i find that it need to spend some times on loading the new userform . That makes the whole application much loading time

Ok You never show progress in the `UserForm_Initialize()` event of the userform. Show the progress when the process actually starts. If required, move everything to `UserForm_Activate()` or in a click of a `Commandbutton`. I am using `UserForm_Click()` for demonstration purpose.

Let's say we have a userform which looks like below with a `Frame` and Listbox` control.

Put this code in the userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    ListBox1.AddItem "I am performing something in a loop..."
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True

    For i = 1 To 10
        Wait 3
    Next i

    ListBox1.AddItem "I am now writing something to the workbook..."
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True

    Range("A1").Value = "Sid"

    ListBox1.AddItem "I am performing something again in a loop..."
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True

    For i = 1 To 10
        Wait 3
    Next i

    '
    '~~> And So on
    '
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

**Logic**:

1. Before starting any process, add the description to the listbox. I have added sample processes and descriptions in the above code. Please amend them to suit your needs.
2. Notice the line `ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True`? This will ensure that the recent most entry is always selected. This also ensure that the Listbox scrolls to the latest entry if many things are added to the listbox.

**In Action**

[image]

**EDIT**

You have misunderstood how it works :)

1. Add a listbox on the form as shown in the image above.
2. Delete all code from the userform and replace it with this code

Now run the code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ListBox1.AddItem "Generating random numbers..."
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True
    DoEvents

    For i = 1 To 1000
        For j = 1 To 1000
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("content").Cells(i, j) = Rnd
        Next
    Next

    ListBox1.AddItem "Copying and working with Content sheet..."
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True
    DoEvents

    Row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("content").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("content").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:A"))
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("B:B"))
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("C:C"))
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("D:D"))
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("E:E"))
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("F:F"))
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("G:G"))
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("H:H"))
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 9) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("I:I"))
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, 10) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:K"))

    ListBox1.AddItem "Saving File..."
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True
    DoEvents

    strFileName = "c:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("content").Cells(1, 1) & ".xlsx"

    wb.SaveAs strFileName
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("content").Cells.Clear

    ListBox1.AddItem "Done!"
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: i have added this userform and code .Then ,how to combine with my button ? When button1 is clicked, this userform opens .What is the procedures to combine with my button(run those actions)  ?

Comment: If `Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()` launches this userform then in the userform's activate event, put all the code. Also if required, add `DoEvents` after every `ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True`

Comment: `ListBox1.AddItem "I am performing something in a loop..."
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True`  Error 424 Need object

Comment: No. you are doing it incorrectly. Put  `userform.show` in `CommandButton3_Clic‌​k‌​()` and the commandbutton's existing code, move it to the above userform's activate event

Comment: Now ,i have done the following procedures:1 ) create userform 2) put your code on UserForm_Click 3) add only 1 sentence on my clickbutton : `userform.show` 4) move all my commandbutton's existing code to userform's activate event

Comment: Now , when i press the command button , the userform comes out first . However ,the userform has nothing shown inside .As it freezes ,hangs and  shows `no responses `on the title . After a while , the userform closes automatically and the report comes out . I don't know it is hardware problem or what

Comment: Did you add `DoEvents` as I mentioned above?

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout Now i add `DoEvents` after every `ListBox1.Selected(L‌​istBox1.ListCount - 1) = True`   3 in total

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121129/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-evabb).

Comment: I knew you were doing something wrong :D. I have updated the above post. See the edit

Comment: thanks bro , i will try the code tmr .One more question .As i have 5 buttons to generate different kind of reports , the codes inside buttons should be different .In this case , should i create 5 more userforms and put those different codes inside respectively ?Any convenient ways?