# Excel VBA UserForm, progress bar

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I've created a userform that should act like progress toolbar and show me my actual progress in percent.

I want to show my tool bar in a for loop. But the for loop doesn't go on only if i click away the userform. What i am doing wrong?

```
For k = 1 To 300

    pctcompl = k * 100 / 300

    UserForm1.Text.Caption = pctcompl & "% Completed"
    UserForm1.Bar.Width = pctcompl * 2

    DoEvents

    UserForm1.Show

Next k
```

Comment: Please copy paste the code into the question, don't add it as a picture!

Comment: Pick your best answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181164/progress-bar-in-vba-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me google that for you :-)

frmTest.Show vbModeless

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/41673-userform-stops-macro-how-continue-w-still-visible.html

Works for me :-)