# Progress Bar to show how much of the process is completed Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have written code to copy paste certain rows from one workbook to another.
I want a progress bar to show me the progress of the job taking into account each row pasted.
For example: If I have to copy-paste 10 rows, then once 1 row is pasted it should show: 10% completed.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
 Sub Automate_Estimate()

 Set Wb = ThisWorkbook                  

 MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)

    Application.StatusBar = "Copying In progress..." & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row & "% completed"

    Debug.Print MyFile, DestName

        Set rng = Sheets(SourceName).Range("C12:R12")
        rng.Copy

        Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Set rng = Sheets(SourceName).Range("C30:R30")
        rng.Copy

        Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(24, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Set rng = Sheets(SourceName).Range("C22:R22")
        rng.Copy

        Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(4, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Set rng = Sheets(SourceName).Range("C20:R20")
        rng.Copy

        Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(14, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Set rng = Sheets(SourceName).Range("C40:R40")
        rng.Copy

        Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(17, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Set rng = Sheets(SourceName).Range("C16:R16")
        rng.Copy

        Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(7, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Set rng = Sheets(SourceName).Range("C17:R17")
        rng.Copy

        Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(8, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Set rng = Sheets(SourceName).Range("C21:R21")
        rng.Copy

        Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(16, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Set rng = Sheets(SourceName).Range("C52:R52")
        rng.Copy

        Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(56, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Application.StatusBar = "Copying Is complete"

        wkb.Close
    End Sub
```

The progress bar code is after 'Set wkb' (After line 2). The data is being pasted from the 2nd column.
Can somebody help me with this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the StatusBar after every Copy to show a new text.

You could define a small SubRoutine:

```
Sub CopyRange(fromRange As Range, toRange As Range, completed As Double)
    fromRange.Copy
    toRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.StatusBar = "Copying In progress..." & Round(completed, 0) & "% completed"
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Define a Constant that holds the number of steps and increase a variable after every step:

```
Sub Automate_Estimate()
    Const Steps = 10
    Dim completed As Double

    ' ... (Set your Wb stuff here)
    completed = 0
    Application.StatusBar = "Copying In progress..."

    Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C12:R12"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(1, 2), completed)
    completed = completed + (100 / Steps)
    ' ... (Add all your copying here and increase completed after every step)
    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it's still not working. Called the subroutine in my main Sub like you mentioned.

Comment: I mean, there is no Progress bar visible. Sorry, I'm new to VBA.

Comment: Should be - I tested it and it shows up to me. You are aware that it's rather small at the bottom of the Excel window? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12918056/7599798

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. The progress bar shows "Copying in Progress..." but doesn't show the percentage completion.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code as suggested by @FunThomas

Second sub which is used to call

```
Sub CopyRange(fromRange As Range, toRange As Range, completed As Double)
fromRange.Copy
toRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.StatusBar = "Copying In progress..." & Round(completed, 0) & "% 
completed"
DoEvents
End Sub
```

This is the Main Sub

```
Sub Automate_Estimate()
Dim completed As Double

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Const steps = 9                                                            
'Number of rows copied



    MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel 
   Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")


    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)

    completed = 0
    Application.StatusBar = "Copying In progress..."



        Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C12:R12"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(1, 2), completed)
        completed = completed + (100 / steps)

        Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C30:R30"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(24, 2), completed)
        completed = completed + (100 / steps)


        Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C22:R22"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(4, 2), completed)
        completed = completed + (100 / steps)

        Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C20:R20"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(14, 2), completed)
        completed = completed + (100 / steps)


        Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C40:R40"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(17, 2), completed)
        completed = completed + (100 / steps)

        Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C16:R16"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(7, 2), completed)
        completed = completed + (100 / steps)

        Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C17:R17"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(8, 2), completed)
        completed = completed + (100 / steps)

        Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C21:R21"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(16, 2), completed)
        completed = completed + (100 / steps)


        Call CopyRange(Sheets(SourceName).Range("C52:R52"), Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(56, 2), completed)
        completed = completed + (100 / steps)


        Application.StatusBar = False

        wkb.Close

    DoEvents
 End Sub
```