# Excel VBA progress indicator

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Excel VBA code I got from the Internet that lists all the files in a Folder. My problem is I want a progress indicator to prompt the user that the macro is still running.

Here is the Code...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Worksheets("GetFileList").Unprotect 'Unprotect Sheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$
    InitialFoldr$ = "C:\"
    Worksheets("GetFileList").Range("A4:a5000").Clear 'Clear selected range
    ActiveSheet.Range("a4").Select               'Set Focus

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
    .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
             xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
             xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
        Do While xFname$ <> ""
            ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xFname$
            xRow = xRow + 1
            xFname$ = Dir
           Loop
        End If
        End With
Worksheets("GetFileList").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
MsgBox "Done Processing...!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Googling "VBA progess indicator" might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following class which I improved to fit my needs.

So it looks something like this in the status bar of Excel:

[image]

---

1. Add a new class module and name it `ProgressBar` with the following code:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private statusBarState As Boolean
   Private enableEventsState As Boolean
   Private screenUpdatingState As Boolean
   Private Const NUM_BARS As Integer = 50
   Private Const MAX_LENGTH As Integer = 255
   Private CharBar As String
   Private CharSpace As String
   Private CharStart As String
   Private CharEnd As String

   Private Sub Class_Initialize()
       ' Save the state of the variables to change
       statusBarState = Application.DisplayStatusBar
       enableEventsState = Application.EnableEvents
       screenUpdatingState = Application.ScreenUpdating
       ' set the progress bar chars (should be equal size)
       CharBar = ChrW(9608)
       CharSpace = ChrW(9617) 'ChrW(12288)
       CharStart = ChrW(9621)
       CharEnd = ChrW(9615)

       ' Set the desired state
       Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
   '    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   '    Application.EnableEvents = False
   End Sub

   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
       ' Restore settings
       Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
       Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdatingState
       Application.EnableEvents = enableEventsState
       Application.StatusBar = False
   End Sub

   Public Function Update(ByVal Value As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal MaxValue As Long = 0, _
                     Optional ByVal Status As String = "", _
                     Optional ByVal StatusEnd As String = "", _
                     Optional ByVal DisplayPercent As Boolean = True) As String

       ' Value          : 0 to 100 (if no max is set)
       ' Value          : >=0 (if max is set)
       ' MaxValue       : >= 0
       ' Status         : optional message to display for user
       ' DisplayPercent : Display the percent complete after the status bar

       ' <Status> <Progress Bar> <Percent Complete>

       ' Validate entries
       If Value < 0 Or MaxValue < 0 Or (Value > 100 And MaxValue = 0) Then Exit Function

       ' If the maximum is set then adjust value to be in the range 0 to 100
       If MaxValue > 0 Then Value = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((Value * 100) / MaxValue, 0)

       ' Message to set the status bar to
       Dim Display As String
       Display = Status & "  " & CharStart

       ' Set bars
       Display = Display & String(Int(Value / (100 / NUM_BARS)), CharBar)
       ' set spaces
       Display = Display & String(NUM_BARS - Int(Value / (100 / NUM_BARS)), CharSpace)

       ' Closing character to show end of the bar
       Display = Display & CharEnd

       If DisplayPercent = True Then Display = Display & "  (" & Value & "%)  "

       Display = Display & "  " & StatusEnd

       ' chop off to the maximum length if necessary
       If Len(Display) > MAX_LENGTH Then Display = Right(Display, MAX_LENGTH)

       Update = Display
       Application.StatusBar = Display
   End Function
   ```
2. Use it as follows in your already existing code:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub TestProgressBar()
       Dim Progress As New ProgressBar

       Dim i As Long
       For i = 1 To 10
           Progress.Update i, 10, "Some Text before", "SomeTextAfter", True
           Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
       Next i
   End Sub
   ```

*The above code is a improved version of the original code that was found here:

[Progress bar in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181164/progress-bar-in-vba-excel/50060974#50060974)*

Comment: Hi, it does not work on me, new to VBA please help me where to put this code.

Comment: It's all in my answer. The first one into a new class module that you name `ProgressBar` the second one into a new module (for testing) and then you need to integrate the second one into your `CommandButton1_Click` as you need it. I cannot give you a copy paste solution for this you need to put in some effort on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll figure it out.