# Progress bar using VBA

Tags: vba, progress-bar, vba7, vba6

I'm working on excel sheet using VBA: I'm trying to test a progress bar. I already completed the design, as shown below:

[image: Design]

Below the `userForm` code:

```
'PLACE IN YOUR USERFORM CODE
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
#If IsMac = False Then
    'hide the title bar if you're working on a windows machine. Otherwise, just display it as you normally would
    Me.Height = Me.Height - 10
    HideTitleBar.HideTitleBar Me
#End If
End Sub
```

Below the `Module` code:

```
'PLACE IN A STANDARD MODULE
Sub LoopThroughRows()
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim pctdone As Single
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'(Step 1) Display your Progress Bar
ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
ufProgress.Show
For i = 1 To lastrow
'(Step 2) Periodically update progress bar
    pctdone = i / lastrow
    With ufProgress
        .LabelCaption.Caption = "Processing Row " & i & " of " & lastrow
        .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
    End With
    DoEvents
        '--------------------------------------
        'the rest of your macro goes below here
        '
        '
        '--------------------------------------
'(Step 3) Close the progress bar when you're done
    If i = lastrow Then Unload ufProgress
Next i
End Sub
```

When I run the code, I get this error:
[image: Debug screen]

And when I press on `Debug`, it highlights on this:

> ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0

More information

UserForm  name is (**ufProgress**) , The label that in the upper left of UserForm that will be used to display the text indicating the status name (**LabelCaption**) ... And the frame on UserForm name (**FrameProgress** ) .. Finlay , the another label, that going to grow progresses indicator name (**LabelProgress**) ..

Any advice ...

Kind Regards

Comment: Consider writing to the StatusBar and updating from there - it is as informative as the form, but not so pretty. And really quicker. E.g. - `Application.StatusBar = "Progress - " & i / lastRow`

Comment: @Vityata , Thanks for your replay, Actually i didn't got you .. where i can add this line

Comment: After `For i = 1 To lastrow`. And delete the rest of the code, it becomes useless. Take a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12918056/5448626

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A userform in VBA is an object, and you need to create an instance of an object before you can use it. But this fact is well hidden by the behavior of VBA to create a default instance of an userform if you access it via it's class name (form name).

Consider you have a form named `Form1` and you write `Form1.Show`: VBA would create an instance of the form and display it.

The alternative is to declare a variable of type of the form, create it manually and then work with that variable:

```
Dim ufProgress as Form1
set ufProgress = new Form1
ufProgress.Show
```

It is usually better to do the last, but in you special case, you could go ahead with the default instance - as the form is just used for displaying (if you enter data into a user form and want to do something with it, using the default instance can lead to some unexpected problems).

---

Still considering that you form is named "Form1", you could solve the problem by

a) rename the form to `ufProgress`
b) replace `ufProgress` with `Form1` in your code
(in both cases, you would access the automatically generated instance of the form)
c) Use the code snippet above.

---

**Update** - after having more information:
The line that is diplayed in the debugger is misleading, the guilty statement is (most likely) within the `UserForm_Initialize`-code of the form, but the debugger doesn't stop there until you tell it do so: In VBA editor, open the Option Window (Tools->Options), choose the General Tab and select "Break in Class modules". I would guess that the command `HideTitleBar.HideTitleBar Me` throws that error. Either remove that line (and live with the fact that the form shows its title) or find the definition for `HideTitleBar`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks i test it and still get error " User defined type not defined " and highlight on " ufProgress As Form1" ... FYI , my user form name is "ufProgress"

Comment: If your form name is `ufProgress`, then of course you cannot declare a variable of type `Form1` - my answer was considering that your form name is `Form1` (haven't seen your first image as you haven't embedded it into your question). In that case you are already working with the default instance and you don't need the variable. Has your form a label called `LabelProgress`?

Comment: yes , (UserForm >> ufProgress  ) , The label that in the upper left of UserForm that will be used  to display the text indicating the status  name (LabelCaption) ... And the frame on UserForm name (FrameProgress ) .. Finlay ,  the another label, that going to grow  progresses indicator  name (LabelProgress) ..

Comment: Thanks for your replay ,,, i removed the code in the UserForm .. and it's working fine ,