# VBA does not refresh data when running script, only after

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to refresh data in my excel sheet. The problem is I want to refresh it before i do anything else but it does not work that way- data is refreshed only AFTER script ends.
For example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Name").OLEDBConnection.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ...(not important)"
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

REST OF THE SCRIPT WHICH USES ^ DATA
```

So the rest of my scipt always uses old data. When script it shows refreshed data but it looks like it only hapens AFTER everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA: Screen doesn't refresh during loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015962/excel-vba-screen-doesnt-refresh-during-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try inserting this line, before refreshing:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Name").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
```

Otherwise, Excel makes the refreshing in background and let the code to continue, processing what exists...

Comment: It fixed the problem. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Jorhanc: Glad I could help!