# Continually Updating Dashboard Loop with Refresh

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a dashboard. The goal is to query data and refresh the dashboard about every minute.

Employees are working through a continual flow of work.
The dashboard needs to query data, replace the data in the dashboard, refresh the dashboard visual so the change can be seen, wait about a minute, and repeat the process.

It is looping through the iterations but not refreshing. I need this loop to stop once a cycle and display the updates.
It is looping but it is frozen until I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Is there any code that can make this loop stop for a second so it can display what has changed since the last loop iteration?

The dashboard is named Summary in the VBA properties.

```vb
For cycle_count = 1 To cycles
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Summary.Range("F3").Value = cycle_count
        
    If cycle_count > 1 Then
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:45"))
    End If
    
    Calculate
        
    SQL_MR.SQL_MR
    SQL_Issues.SQL_Issue_Import
        
    If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
        DoEvents
    End If
        
    Calculate
        
    Summary_Build.service_window
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Summary.Activate
        
Next
```

Comment: try a **DoEvents** statement after the ScreenUpdating = true

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.  I thought it was but it didn't.  I have a cycle counter on the dashboard and it said "15" and after I pressed ESC it immediately displayed 25.  So it wasn't refreshing.  Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: is the dashboard on a Form, if so follow the DoEvents with a **Me.Repaint** to hopefully redraw the form.

Comment: It isn't a form.  It's just an excel worksheet.  The VBA is clearing contents and inserting values from a refreshed query into the cleared cells.

Comment: explore this post
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735378/force-a-screen-update-in-excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735378/force-a-screen-update-in-excel-vba)