Restoring Excel Display Size
I have a timer application that I want to run in a reduced size with no toolbar so I execute this in ThisWorkbook:
Sub SetWindowSize1()
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "Timer1.xlsm" Then
        Application.WindowState = xlNormal
        Application.Top = 25
        Application.Left = 25
        Application.Width = 300
        Application.Height = 300
        Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    End If
End Sub

That works just fine but when I exit the application in Module1 with:
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "1" Then
        WrapUp
        End
    End If

Sub WrapUp()
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "0"
        Application.WindowState = xlNormal
        Application.Top = 25
        Application.Left = 25
        Application.Width = 1000
        Application.Height = 600
        Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
    End
End Sub

Exiting the macro shows the expected increased size and the Toolbar. Opening another spreadsheet shows the Toolbar correctly but the size remains reduced.

There is a dangling End in WrapUp

That End halts macro execution. Oops, I see it is redundant! However, it has no effect on functionality. Subsequent spreadsheets still open in the reduced size.

Try this from an old post about forcing a screen update  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735378/force-a-screen-update-in-excel-vba

I don't think that is applicable to my situation. The Toolbar display updates correctly but the spreadsheet display area does not.

I think that the windows operating system stores the applications last used dimensions. When that is the problem here than there is not much to do about it in vba.
Maybe you could try Application.Quit instead of End after you've restored the original dimensions. Whether you need to save before that is up to you.

Thanks, but the result is still the same. Timer is restored to full size but even when I save it, a subsequent spreadsheet opens at the reduced size.

Even if I resize the window manually, the reduced effect does not go away until I resize ANOTHER spreadsheet.

I got it to work finally!
Sub WrapUp()
With Application
.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.Toolbar(""Ribbon"",True)"
.WindowState=xlNormal
.CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible=True
.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled=True
.DisplayStatusBar=True
.DisplayScrollBars=True
.DisplayFormulaBar=True
.Width=1000
.Height=600
.Top=25
.Left=25
End With
With ActiveWindow
.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
.DisplayRuler = True
.DisplayHeadings = True
End With
End Sub
